# Selendroid in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, selendroid

I'm using Android studio to build a projects 
My Question is there any way to setup Selendroid in **Android studio**? Please Teach me step by step.

I already added this to my Gradle

> In my Gradle Project:

```
 dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
        compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.48.2'
    }buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

> In my Module app:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.47.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

> My Main Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SelendroidCapabilities capa = new SelendroidCapabilities("io.selendroid.testapp:0.17.0");

    WebDriver driver = new WebDriver(capa);
    WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.id("my_text_field"));
    Assert.assertEquals("true", inputField.getAttribute("enabled"));
    inputField.sendKeys("Selendroid");
    Assert.assertEquals("Selendroid", inputField.getText());
    driver.quit();
}
```

**My Error is         SelendroidCapabilities capa = new SelendroidCapabilities("io.selendroid.testapp:0.17.0");
Error:(5, 1) error: package io.selendroid.client does not exist**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write anything in MainActivity instead create a new Java Class ins scr-> Main -> add your Test case code there.

then go to build variant -> select Unit Tests and run the Test case

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.selendroid/selendroid-client/0.17.0) to your project!(eclipse: Right click to your project -> Build Path -> Add external Archives... -> Choose the downloaded .jar file.)
Hope this help!

Comment: im using Android studio  not Eclipse

Comment: I mean you missed necessary .jar() files. So try to find the way to add .jar files to Android Studio